AWS CDK: Create a Subnet and Launch Instance in it With Existing VPC
I have a fairly simple task that I am unable to complete with AWS CDK: Create a subnet and launch an instance in it using an existing VPC.
The existing VPC is a CfnVpc that I obtained using the cdk migrate command. Here it is:
class Lab(Stack):

    @property
    def vpc(self) -> ec2.CfnVPC:
        return self._vpc

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(
            scope, construct_id, description="Nat instance with two subnets", **kwargs
        )
        self._vpc = ec2.CfnVPC(
            self,
            "VPC",
            enable_dns_support=True,
            enable_dns_hostnames=True,
            cidr_block=subnetConfig["VPC"]["CIDR"],
            tags=[
                {
                    "key": "Application",
                    "value": self.stack_name,
                },
                {
                    "key": "Network",
                    "value": "PublicA",
                },
            ],
        )

Here are my new resources:
class MyResources(Lab):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(
            self, "L2VPC", tags={"aws:cloudformation:logical-id": "VPC"}
        )

        publicSubnetB = ec2.Subnet(
            self,
            "PublicSubnetB",
            availability_zone="us-east-1b",
            cidr_block="10.0.2.0/24",
            vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id,
        )
        cdk.Tags.of(publicSubnetB).add("Application", self.stack_name)
        cdk.Tags.of(publicSubnetB).add("Network", "PublicB")

        # These are also exposed from the cdk migrate command via properties. 
        ec2.CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation(
            self,
            "PublicSubnetBRouteTableAssociation",
            subnet_id=publicSubnetB.subnet_id,
            route_table_id=self.publicRouteTable.ref,
        )
        ec2.CfnSubnetNetworkAclAssociation(
            self,
            "PublicSubnetBNetworkAclAssociation",
            subnet_id=publicSubnetB.subnet_id,
            network_acl_id=self.publicNetworkAcl.ref,
        )

And finally, here's the failing instance:
        instanceB = ec2.Instance(
            self,
            "InstanceB",
            instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(
                instance_class=ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE3,
                instance_size=ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO,
            ),
            machine_image=ec2.AmazonLinuxImage(
                generation=ec2.AmazonLinuxGeneration.AMAZON_LINUX_2
            ),
            vpc=vpc,
            vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
                subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC, availability_zones=["us-east-1b"]
            ),
            user_data=ec2.UserData.custom(userDataB),
            private_ip_address="10.0.2.119",
            associate_public_ip_address=True,
            security_group=sg,
            user_data_causes_replacement=True,
        )

AWS CDK says that there is no public subnet in az us-east-1b - even though I created it just prior. The only way this works is if I comment out the instance code, run it, clear the context, run it again, and comment back in the instance code. There has got to be a better way!

I'm not sure what the best solution here would be, but it's happening because you are using VPC lookup. Before you deploy the VPC with Lab, there is no VPC to lookup. If you can get a proper VPC construct instead of CfnVPC, you could use that instead of the lookup and then it would work.

@kichik That's unfortunately not an option because the CfnVpc has a bunch of resources in it already, I used cdk migrate to convert the existing CloudFormation template into code. I'd have to refactor the entire thing (I think)?

Or create a whole new VPC with the L2 construct and move stuff there.

@kichik I've considered it... but that's craziness. I moved away from TF bc of the license, CloudFormation has got to have a way to do this. TF would have been extremely simple.

The VPC L2 construct is a bit rigid on that, sadly. They do expect things to be a certain way. It is possible that with enough trial and error you can convert CfnVpc to VPC by setting the configuration of the VPC construct just right. If you haven't already, you should import the subnets and route tables as well. CloudFormation does support that so it should work with cdk import.

Another solution would be to subnet id directly instead of using subnet type. Also, why is it failing to find the subnet, if you migrated an existing one? Shouldn't it already be there?

The solution was very tricky and not well documented in my opinion.
Since I was creating the subnet in the same stack as I used to look up the VPC, I had to use the ec2.Vpc.from_vpc_attributes() class method instead of the ec2.Vpc.from_lookup() class method.
Does not work:
# app.py

vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "IVpc", region="us-east-1")

# ...[create public subnet ref CfnVpc]

# ...[create instance in public subnet] 

Error Logs


jsii.errors.JavaScriptError: 
  Error: To set 'associatePublicIpAddress: true' you must select Public subnets (vpcSubnets: { subnetType: SubnetType.PUBLIC })
      at new Instance (/tmp/jsii-kernel-wHeWcm/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2/lib/instance.js:1:5169)
      at Kernel._Kernel_create (/tmp/tmpxiyze867/lib/program.js:10108:25)
      at Kernel.create (/tmp/tmpxiyze867/lib/program.js:9779:93)
      at KernelHost.processRequest (/tmp/tmpxiyze867/lib/program.js:11696:36)
      at KernelHost.run (/tmp/tmpxiyze867/lib/program.js:11656:22)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (/tmp/tmpxiyze867/lib/program.js:11657:46)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/acg_nlb_lab/infra/app.py", line 80, in <module>
    MyInfra(app, STACK, env=env)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/cdk-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 118, in __call__
    inst = super(JSIIMeta, cast(JSIIMeta, cls)).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/acg_nlb_lab/infra/app.py", line 55, in __init__
    instanceB = ec2.Instance(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/cdk-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 118, in __call__
    inst = super(JSIIMeta, cast(JSIIMeta, cls)).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/cdk-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aws_cdk/aws_ec2/__init__.py", line 71951, in __init__
    jsii.create(self.__class__, self, [scope, id, props])
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/cdk-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 334, in create
    response = self.provider.create(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/cdk-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 365, in create
    return self._process.send(request, CreateResponse)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/cdk-3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 342, in send
    raise RuntimeError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
RuntimeError: To set 'associatePublicIpAddress: true' you must select Public subnets (vpcSubnets: { subnetType: SubnetType.PUBLIC })



Works:
# app.py

# ...[create public subnet ref CfnVpc]

# ...[create instance in public subnet] 

vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_vpc_attributes(
    self,
    "IVpc",
    vpc_id=self.vpc.ref,
    availability_zones=["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b"],
    public_subnet_ids=[self.publicSubnet.ref, publicSubnetB.subnet_id],
    public_subnet_route_table_ids=[
        self.publicRouteTable.ref,
        self.publicRouteTable.ref,
    ],
)

# ...[able to use L2 IVpc and L2 instance]


It sounds like you need to make it clear to CFN that the instance is dependent upon the subnet being created. You can do something like,
instanceB.node.add_dependency(publicSubnetB)

if they are in the same stack or
the_instance_stack.node.add_dependency(MyResources)

if the instance and the subnet are in different stacks.
